# Moving Average for multiple ID's, by date, not observation, in R

Tags: r, dplyr, moving-average

I have a relatively large dataset (over 1000 obs and growing), with an ID code for each person, a date, and a metric value for each person on each date (with some missing values).

I'm looking to add a column of a simple moving average of that metric for each ID, on each date, ideally through a function where I could reproduce it for multiple date windows of the moving average (5-day,20-day, etc)

Using the answer from another rolling avg question answered here, this solution works if I subset the data into a single ID:

```
rollavgbyperiod <- function(i,window){
  startdate <- dates[i]-window
  enddate <- dates[i]
  interval <- seq(startdate,enddate,1)

  tmp <- df[dates %in% interval,"metric"]
  return(mean(tmp$metric))
}

dates <- as.Date(df$date)
window <- 5
Roll.Av <- sapply(1:length(df$date),function(m) rollavgbyperiod(m,window))
Roll.Av[is.nan(Roll.Av)] <- NA
```

My thought was to use a dplyr summarize after a group_by(df,ID), using the function above, but I'm unable to figure out a working solution for that.

My other approach was trying to split the df into a list by ID, then using lapply on that list, then bringing that list back to one df, but this seems like a cumbersome solution, and again-couldn't find a working solution.

As added context, I'm pulling this data in from an AzureSQL table, which is why I wouldn't be able to just leave it in a list (other uses of this table, like PowerBI-to my knowledge, need tables, correct me if I'm mistaken however).